# Dynamically declared fields in Kohana

Tags: php, kohana

I’ve been building an application with Kohana 3.3, and recently switched development from Coda 2 — a text editor — to PhpStorm 6 — an IDE.

PhpStorm 6 has been very handy in pointing out potential code smells; it prompted me to move from attaching data to views with the `__set($key, $value)` magic method to instead using the `bind($key, $value)` method.

Another thing that PhpStorm 6 is complaining about, is that I’m declaring fields dynamically.

I have subclassed `Controller_Template`, and I’m attaching my view to my template like this:

```
public function action_index() {
    # Create the view
    $view = View::factory('project/list');

    # Attach the view to the template
    $this->template->content = $view;
}
```

Apparently, `content` is declared dynamically. I’ve been checking up the class heirarchy, and I can't find the `content` property declared anywhere (hence why it’s dynamic, I suppose). Is this a code smell? Is dynamic declaration bad? Can I explicitly declare the `content` property somewhere?

As it is, the code works. I just want to understand *why* PhpStorm is giving me a notice, and whether or not I’m going about things the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage and disadvantage of PHP is dynamic typing. Its convenient in some cases, but irritating in another. You shown here irritating example. You know, that the `$view` is object which inherit from `View` (for example), so you know which functions you can use. If you don't mess anything, there will be `View` type object always.

Phpstorm don't have this information and thats why you see warning. He wants you also to be careful with this code but in this case you cannot do nothing. You cannot also cast `$view` to `View` like in Java:

```
$this->template->content = (View)$view; //impossible :(
```

`$view` and `$this->template->content` are dynamic typing variables and you cannot change it. Just take care to not assign another type to your variable and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add some info to the answer Kasyx is giving. Everything he says is correct but there is an alternative to set variables in kohana if you hate dynamic typing or like some clarity in what your views are doing. (Template is just another view ;) )

You can also set variables in views with the `set()` function ([docs](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/View#set)) eg:

```
$view->set('foo', 'my value');
```